# OCMock constraints const char * arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

OCMVerify function invocation, one of the parameters is const char *, how to constraits this type

```
[mock xxx:filter file:file func:__FUNCTION__];
OCMVerify([mock xxxxx:OCMArg.any file:OCMArg.any]);
```

the `xxx` function will call `xxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `anyPointer`. See section 4.1 of the documentation for details.